# save and load Listbox Items locally and pass them to other pages

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am currently working on Windows Store App in c#.

Now,
I am having a list box 'Listbox1' which gets its items on a button click event from a text box 'tasks', and have selected Items delete property on other button click event.

```
private void add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string t;
        t = tasks.Text;
        if (t != "")
        {
            Listbox1.Items.Add(t);
        }
        else
        {
            var a = new MessageDialog("Please Enter the Task First");
            a.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Ok"));
            a.ShowAsync();
        }
        tasks.Text = "";
    }

    private void del_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int p = 0; p < Listbox1.SelectedItems.Count; p++)
        {
            Listbox1.Items.Remove(Listbox1.SelectedItems[p].ToString());
            p--;
        }
    }
```

Now I want to save this list into local application storage, after user complete the changes (on a button click event perhaps).
And also to send all Listbox Items to another page(s).

I am not much a coder, I design things.

Please guide me by sample or reference.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have already stored the data to local storage, you could just read it in the `OnNavigatedTo` override of the other page. Otherwise, use the navigation parameter: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8cb42356-82bc-4d77-9bbc-ae186990cfd5/passing-parameters-during-navigation-in-windows-8

Edit: I am not sure whether you also need some information about local storage. This is easy: `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` has a property called Values, which is a `Dictionary` you can write your settings to. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700361.aspx

Edit: Try something like this code to store your list.

```
// Try to get the old stuff from local storage.
object oldData = null;
ApplicationDataContainer settings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
bool isFound = settings.Values.TryGetValue("List", out oldData);

// Save a list to local storage. (You cannot store the list directly, because it is not
// serialisable, so we use the detours via an array.)
List<string> newData = new List<string>(new string[] { "test", "blah", "blubb" });
settings.Values["List"] = newData.ToArray();

// Test whether the saved list contains the expected data.
Debug.Assert(!isFound || Enumerable.SequenceEqual((string[]) oldData, newData));
```

Note, this is only demo code for testing - it does not make real sense...

Edit: One advice: Do not persist the list in your click handlers as this will become extremely slow as the list grows. I would load and save the list in the Navigation handlers, i.e. add something like

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    if (this.ListBox1.ItemsSource == null) {
        object list;
        if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.TryGetValue("List", out list)) {
            this.ListBox1.ItemsSource = new List<string>((string[]) list);
        } else {
            this.ListBox1.ItemsSource = new List<string>();  
        }
    }
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    if (this.ListBox1.ItemsSource != null) {
        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["List"] = this.ListBox1.ItemsSource.ToArray();         
    }
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```

Comment: nope,
I havent yet stored the data.
And thats what bugging me most as whenever app restarts, all changes are lost.

Comment: Did you write the stuff into the `ApplicationDataContainer`? I have added a sample which works for me. In the first run `isFound` is `false`, afterwards, it should be `true` and `oldData` should hold the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is very nice simple example on SQLite DataBase Use in winRT app Development. Look at it and you will know how you can store your Data on the Local Machine. I learned Basic code from this example.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertgreen/archive/2012/11/13/using-sqlite-in-windows-store-apps.aspx

Now, for ease of navigation let me suggest you a flow for this portion of your app.

> take one `ObservableCollection<>` of `string` and store values of
>   that textBox into this ObservationCollection with `onClick()` and then
>   refer that `ObservableCollection<String>` to the `ItemsList` of the
>   listBox.

now at the time you need to send your Data to the next page, make one parameterised constructor of next page and pass that `ObservableCollection<String>` as it's parameter.

Now you can access those Data in your constructor and can use as however you want.

Hope this will help..